# When using .join to separate all values in a list with commas, why must I add this other line of code for the last value?

Tags: python

I am just starting with python and am at the end of chapter 4 of Automate the Boring Stuff with Python. The project is to use a function to separate all values of a list with commas and the last value having ', and ' before it so as to read when the program is run:

apples, bananas, tofu, and cats

Here is the whole code:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def listFunc(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0: return ''
    if len(lst) == 1: return lst[0]
    firstPart = lst[:-1]
    retFirst = ", ".join(firstPart)
    retSecond = ", and " + lst[-1]
    return retFirst + retSecond;

print(listFunc(spam))
```

My trouble is in these lines:

```
firstPart = lst[:-1]
    retFirst = ", ".join(firstPart)
    retSecond = ", and " + lst[-1]
```

My thought process is the first line here is creating the variable firstPart and assigning it the list up to but not including the last value (cats).

Then the second line here is creating the variable retFirst and assigning to it, each value in the list but with a comma and space at the end so as to look like this: apples, bananas, tofu,

Finally the last line creates the variable retSecond and assigns to it the last value of the list (lst[-1]) but with ", and" before it since in the lst[-1] is after the + operator.

Then when added together in the last line of the function ListFunc, in my eyes it should look like this:

(apples, bananas, tofu, ) + (, and cats)

apples, bananas, tofu, , and cats <-------- two commas

But it comes out the correct way instead of the way I think it will come out. Why does it do this?

Why can I not remove the comma in

```
retFirst = ", and " + lst[-1]
```

and have it come out without two commas in a row. I thought firstPart contained the first three values of the list but I'm obviously wrong.

Please help me to understand how .join works here.

Comment: `join` puts the string 'between' elements of the list (not the end of result).

Comment: change `retSecond = ", and " + lst[-1]` to `retSecond = " and " + lst[-1]`. It works ok.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is when you do `join` is does something like this.

```
yourList = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
print("$".join(yourList))
```

output will be,

> 1$2$3$4

as `join` puts the `joining string` in between the list items, Not at the end of each list item.

In your case,

```
firstPart = lst[:-1] #<-- list : ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu']
retFirst = ", ".join(firstPart) #<-- string: apples, bananas, tofu
retSecond = ", and " + lst[-1] #<-- string: , and cats
return retFirst + retSecond   #<-- string: apples, bananas, tofu, and cats
```

Comment: does this mean when I make the variable firstPart as containing all but the last value (lst[-1]), that specifically 'tofu' becomes the new last value and so when I use join it doesn't put a comma after the new last value?

Comment: Yes. You are slicing the list in such a way, that the last value will be removed.